# replace string with patterns in file

Tags: go, sed, golint

I've used sed to replace variables on *.go files using `sed -i 's/\<old_name\>/newName/g' *.go`
My objective is to eliminate golinter errors.
How can strings with common patterns, e.g. replace 1 with 2

1. `fmt.Printf("blah blah blah")` or `fmt.Printf("yadda yadda yadda")`
2. `fmt.Println("blah blah blah")` or `fmt.Println("yadda yadda yadda")`

In this case, we do NOT want to replace: 
1. `fmt.Printf("print speed= %d",speed)` //So the key here is the ending pattern should be `")`. 
2. log.Printf statements //only replace "fmt."
Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm slightly confused by your question, but think you're trying to do the following:

```
replace      printf("yada yada yada") with println("yada yada yada")
not replace  printf("print speed = %d", speed)
```

If that is the case, I would do something like the following:

```
sed -i '/Printf(\".*\")/ s/Printf/Println/g' *.go
```

That should leave cases intact where you actually want to use formatting. Here is an example:

```
[sborza@msandn]:~$ cat tester.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        speed = 1
        fmt.Printf("vim-go")
        fmt.Printf("speed = %d\n", speed)
}

[sborza@msandn]:~$ sed '/Printf(\".*\")/ s/Printf/Println/g' tester.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        speed = 1
        fmt.Println("vim-go")
        fmt.Printf("speed = %d\n", speed)
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to replace `printf`, not `Printf`. And the greedy pattern `.*` may have unexpected results if there are several `printf` on the same line(some ending with `")`, some not.

Comment: That's fine, the example holds in either case. Fair point on the greediness, but as a quick + dirty fix this is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
gofmt -w -r "printf -> println" .
```

Note that make backup file before do this.